# How to achieve same on mysql? sprintf('%0.2f', $value)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code:

order_total = `216.61` (any)

```
$order=sprintf('%0.2f', str_replace(',', '.', $order_total/1.21));
```

That returns `179.02`

I need same result in my query in where clause

```
i.paid < i.order_total/1.21
```

but in MySQL query i get `179.016529`

The question is how to get same result in MySQL as it is on PHP?

Comment: Is this enough: `SELECT ROUND(216.61/1.21,2);`

Comment: I just did like this `format(i.order_total/1.21, 2)` :) but thanks allot!

Comment: @Ingus in case you need it to compare the value you'd better stick to `ROUND`

Comment: @Teneff Why so?

Comment: Yeah round seems to be better option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again i found answer right after i posted question. .. :D

What i need to use is like this:

```
i.paid < format(i.order_total/1.21, 2)
```